# Django: where is "contrib.auth.login" and "contrib.auth.logout" defined?

Tags: django, authentication

In Django there's an "auth" module, and it apparently has "auth.login" and "auth.logout" functions.

But I can't find them defined anywhere?? Inside the auth folder (under the Python directory, Lib / site-packages / django / contrib ... etc) I looked through every py file.

Am I missing something here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
django/contrib/auth/__init__.py
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... I guess I lied when I said I read through every file inside the directory, never thought it'd be in the __init__.py file! Thanks!

Comment: @whoever downgraded this answer: this is exactly the right answer, why did you downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

From the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-out

> To log out a user who has been logged in via
>   django.contrib.auth.login(), use django.contrib.auth.logout() within
>   your view. It takes an HttpRequest object and has no return value.

Example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```